# Line quality is very low with jagged or blurry edges

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, graphics, graphics2d

I'm working on a drawing app and the line quality seems to be very low and jagged compared to other drawing apps.

Or it might be that other apps are doing something different than I'm doing.

What I have done so far is use the graphics property to draw the lines. I also collect the mouse positions on the mouse move events for assigning to a path later on. Summarized it:

MouseDownHandler:

```
mouseDownPoint.x = event.stageX;
mouseDownPoint.y = event.stageY;
drawCommands.push(GraphicsPathCommand.MOVE_TO);
simplePath = "M " + mouseDownPoint.x + " " + mouseDownPoint.y;
```

MouseMoveHandler:

```
line.graphics.lineStyle(lineWeight, lineColor, lineAlpha, pixelHinting);
line.graphics.moveTo(previousPoint.x, previousPoint.y);
scaledPoint = new Point(localPoint.x/scaleX, localPoint.y/scaleY);
line.graphics.lineTo(scaledPoint.x, scaledPoint.y);
previousPoint.x = scaledPoint.x;
previousPoint.y = scaledPoint.y;
simplePath += " L " + scaledPoint.x + " " + scaledPoint.y;
```

MouseUpHandler:

myPath.data = simplePath;

As I draw I update the line (which is a UIComponent but could just as well be a Shape or Sprite - anything with a graphics property). At the same time I keep track of the mouse locations in the simplePath string.

When the mouse is up I clear the line graphics and show a path graphic element. The Path isn't important to this but I noticed it looks slightly cleaner than the line that had been drawn. That might be because it has pixel hinting (it's not much cleaner). Sometimes there are artifacts. And I'm including it in case I need to use a path for some reason.

Here is the screen shot:

[image: without pixel hinting]
[image: with pixel hinting]

The pixel hinted version looks crisper but it still is far below the quality of the line drawing in other apps and in some cases it makes it look more jagged. Is there something I'm missing?

Note: I included graphics2d and canvas2d because I believe this may not be related to the specific language or platform but might be related to drawing graphics in general.

Comment: You might probably want to add some smoothing to that zigzag the user might input. Like green bezier curve here: http://delimiter.ru/temp/bezier.png

Comment: @Organis Yeah. That looks great! That's what I'm missing. What do I need to do? Where do I start?

Comment: I'll post the math in a few minutes.

Answer (score 3):

The green line is produced by **Graphics.cubicCurveTo(...)** method. Initially you have a list of user-provided points A1,A2,A3...An. In order to use cubic curves you also need to figure 2 control points CFk (forward) and CBk (backward), for each Ak respectively, so you draw that big curve starting from A1 and every curve piece from Ak-1 to Ak will take arguments **.cubicCurveTo(CFk-1, CBk, Ak);**

For each Ak (except for A1 and An) you can calculate CFk and CBk as following:

```
(vector)AForward = (vector)(Ak+1 - Ak-1)
(vector)AForward.length = (vector)(Ak+1 - Ak).length / 3

CFk = Ak + (point)AForward

(vector)ABackward = (vector)(Ak-1 - Ak+1)
(vector)ABackward.length = (vector)(Ak-1 - Ak).length / 3

CBk = Ak + (point)ABackward
```

Then, there are A1 and An that are left out, but I am sure you can figure them on your own.

For vector math you can use **ru.delimiter.math.Vector2D** class (works with both Cartesian and Polar coordinates) from my small collection of useful things: https://bitbucket.org/thydmitry/ru.delimiter/src/9083fb46ce1c/classes/ru/delimiter/math/

**P.S.** Maybe you don't need to go that extreme and will be fine with the red line, that is a simple **.curveTo(Ak, (Ak + Ak+1)/2);**

**UPD**: a simple algorithm to inscribe a curve into zigzag provided by an array of points.

```
function middle(A:Point, B:Point):Point
{
    return new Point((A.x + B.x) / 2, (A.y + B.y) / 2);
}

function drawTo(target:Point):void
{
    graphics.lineTo(target.x, target.y);
}

function bendTo(control:Point, target:Point):void
{
    graphics.curveTo(control.x, control.y, target.x, target.y);
}

// This should contain at least 2 points before you start drawing.
var PP:Vector.<Point>;

// Go to the start position.
graphics.lineStyle(0, 0xFF0000);
graphics.moveTo(PP[0].x, PP[0].y);

// Draw a straight line to the center of the first zigzag segment.
drawTo(middle(PP[0], PP[1]));

// For each 3 consequent points A,B and C, connect
// the middle of AB and the middle of BC with a curve.
for (var i:int = 2; i < PP.length; i++)
{
    bendTo(PP[i - 1], middle(PP[i - 1], PP[i]));
}

// Connect the center of the last zigzag segment with the end point.
drawTo(PP[PP.length - 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons:

- Stage quality. In Flash Player you can set the [stage quality](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageQuality.html) to LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH, BEST, 8x8, 8x8Linear, 16x16 and 16x16Linear. This affects if there is antialiasing applied on lines / paths and how many times it's applied. Increasing the quality helps but in 8x8 and higher quality there are bugs in the Flash Player (font size reduced by 25% on non-embedded fonts, graphics artifacts, gradient fills color count reduced).
- Pixel snapping. If you have a 1px line that ends up positioned on a half pixel it is anti aliased over two lines. Normally antialiasing increases quality but in the case of an offset single pixel line it reduces quality. Setting pixel snapping helps.
- Using curveTo and cubicCurveTo instead of line points as @Organis  suggested. Not sure how to do this yet.

Will try to post images of the difference in each case when I get a chance.